# Is it possible to programatically open the settings app? (not the app settings within the settings app)

Tags: ios

I want my app to be able to launch the user into the iTunes & App Store section of the Settings app.
This doesn't seem to be possible so instead I would like to just take the user to the top level of the Settings app so they can access the iTunes & App Store section from there.

Is this possible? All previous answers relating to this are regarding launching into the *app's settings* within the Settings app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, use `UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"App-Prefs:root=STORE")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)` to open AppStore Settings. It may not work on Simulator but it works on real device.